# Does voting to leave open do anything or is it like the 'close door' button on an elevator?

Tags: support, closing, review

I enjoy voting to leave open a question when the OP has clearly modified their original post or when it seems like others are bullying the OP. But I don't see how it is at all different from "Skip", because it doesn't seem to delete other close votes. Is it there just to make you feel good (like [the close button on elevators](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2979/14237))?

Comment: Theoretically, if enough people "leave open" then the closure votes decay starts sooner.

Comment: When I vote to "leave open" I leave a comment asking the close voters to give some sort of feedback to the OP. Usually these questions remain open - this is either because everyone agrees with me (maybe I am careful with my "leave open" votes?) or no one can be bothered to give feedback but they now feel guilty voting to close whilst not giving feedback...

Comment: See meta.SO: [What exactly happens with the button “Leave Open” (previously “Do Not Close”)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close)